# How to get "Name" from nslookup in Go?

Tags: go

I see the following response when I run nslookup command from inside a pod running in a  Kubernetes cluster.

```
root@ubuntu:/# nslookup kubernetes.default.svc
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

How can I do the same in Go? It seems that Go has Lookup* methods which only return the IP address. But I want to know the domain name for which this response was returned. In fact, I am looking for a way to find the fully qualified domain name this way.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use below API might be it will help.

**API** - import "net"

**Method**
`func (r *Resolver) LookupHost(ctx context.Context, host string) (addrs []string, err error)`

**More details about complete API**

- https://golang.org/src/net/lookup.go?s=5598:5689#L165
- https://golang.org/pkg/net/#pkg-examples

Comment: LookupHost returns IP addresses, not DNS names.